# Node-Sass unsupported version in docker container on minikube/k8s with shared volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, webpack-dev-server, minikube, node-sass

I'm porting a node/react/webpack app to k8s, and am trying to configure a development environment that makes use of the hot-reloading feature of webpack. I'm hitting an error when running this with a shared volume on `minikube`:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"data":"$primary: #f9427f;$secondary: #171735;$navbar-back-rotation: 0;$navbar-link-rotation: 0;$login-background: url('/images/login-background.jpg');$secondary-background: url('/images/secondary-bg.jpg');"}!./src/sass/style.sass
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (67)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
```

Running the code in the container by itself (mostly) works--it starts up without errors and serves the page via `docker run -it --rm --name=frontend --publish=3000:3000 <container hash>`

```
#Dockerfile

FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir /code
ADD . /code/
WORKDIR /code/
RUN yarn cache clean && yarn install --non-interactive  && npm rebuild node-sass

CMD npm run dev-docker
```

where `dev-docker` in `package.json` is `NODE_ENV=development npm run -- webpack --progress --hot --watch`

In the following, commenting out the `volumeMounts` key eliminates the error.

```
# deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: web
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend-container
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: frontend-repo
        hostPath:
          path: /Users/me/Projects/code/frontend
      containers:
        - name: web-container
          image: localhost:5000/react:dev
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 3000
            protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
          - name: frontend-repo
            mountPath: /code
          env:
           ... # redacted for simplicity, assume works
```

Based on what i've found elsewhere, I believe that the os-native binding used by `node-sass` are interfering between host and container when the shared volume is introduced. That is, the image build process creates the bindings that would work for the container, but those are overwritten when the shared volume is mounted.

Is this understanding correct? How do I best structure things so that a developer can work on their local repo and see those changes automatically reflected in the cluster instance, without rebuilding images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hypothesis was borne out--the node modules were being built for the container, but overwritten by the `volumeMount`. The approach that worked best at this point was to do the requirements building as the entrypoint of the container, so that it would run when the container started up, rather than only at build time.

```
# Dockerfile

CMD RUN yarn cache clean && yarn install --non-interactive --force && npm run dev-docker
```